# Sobre a etimologia do sobrenome Sodré

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, nomes, história

Sempre que passo no [Cais do Sodré](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cais_do_Sodr%C3%A9) em Lisboa, penso sobre a origem do sobrenome "Sodré". A origem do mesmo é conhecida?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o historiador e escritor britânico [Roger Crowley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Crowley)†, em alguns casos, o sobrenome [Sodré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodr%C3%A9) é a versão lusa de [Sudeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudeley):

> It’s often said that England and Portugal are Europe’s oldest allies. Both are seafaring countries on the Atlantic sea board which traded with each other in medieval times. English crusaders stopped off at Lisbon in 1147 and helped the king of Portugal expel the Muslim rulers of the city. Many of the English stayed and settled down. Trading links and agreements followed. In 1373 Edward III concluded a treaty with the envoys of the Portuguese king to send archers to resist attacks from the larger neighbouring kingdom of Castile. 
>  It was eight years before an expeditionary force could be assembled. The Duke of Cambridge gathered some 3000 men at Plymouth. Amongst those who went was ‘Frederick Sudley of Gloucestershire’. Frederick evidently originated from Sudeley, near Winchcombe, but his exact origins seem uncertain. He could not have been a son of John de Sudeley, 3rd Baron Sudeley, who died in 1367, as he had no direct heirs, but it’s possible to hazard a guess that he was a member of the family, and a figure of some importance. If so, Frederick would have contributed his own band of men-at-arms and archers to the expedition. Eight ships from Bristol sailed round to Plymouth to join the Duke of Cambridge – it seems likely that Sudley and his Gloucestershire contingent made the journey on these ships. They finally landed at Lisbon in June 1381. 
>  The English expedition achieved nothing. The men were unpaid and the whole enterprise quickly collapsed. After a few months they returned home. However Frederick Sudley decided to stay in Portugal where he prospered. His name, rendered as Sodré in Portuguese, became prominent. He had a son João (John) and a grand-daughter Isabel who married Estêvão da Gama, from a wealthy and titled family. Vasco, their son, was Frederick’s great-grandson. 
>  It has to be said that the Sodrés and the Gamas were a rough lot. Two of Isabel’s brothers, Vicente and Brás Sodré, accompanied Vasco on his second expedition to India. These Sodrés were Vasco’s uncles but were hardly older than him. The Anglo-Portuguese crusading tendency remained strong.

<sub>† Roger Crowley, [Gloucestershire man discovers India... sort of...](http://rogercrowley.blogspot.com/2016/03/gloucestershire-man-discovers-indiasort.html), 2016.</sub>

Comment: Eu acho esta fonte duvidosa pela simples razão de não fornecer documentos sólidos para fundamentar a sua tese. **É frequente haver literatura inglesa pseudo-científica que tenta reclamar ou distorcer feitos portugueses ou de outros paises**. É parecido com a tese de que a palavra japonesa *"arigato"* tem origem na palavra portuguesa *"obrigado"* o que em geral não se acredita ser verdade. O problema dessa tese é ser anterior aos cadernos paroquiais do séc XVI e portanto até as árvores genealógicas que possam suportar a mudança de grafia no nome podem não existir.

Comment: Menos mau o autor dizer: **"but it’s possible to hazard a guess"**. Não faltam autores a fazer conjecturas dessas sem incluir a ressalva que estão a adivinhar.

Comment: @bad_coder Sim, mas o Roger Crowley ajudou imenso a popularizar os feitos dos portugueses de há 500 anos.  Sendo ele historiador, ao publicar artigos com afirmações destas, ele está a por a sua reputação profissional em jogo. De qualquer forma, seria interessante encontrar outras origens de Sodré. Possivelmente, Sudeley virou Sodré porque Sodré já existia e soava parecido

Comment: Está aqui um artigo com as especulações em torno do nome [Sodré](https://www.parentesco.com.br/pdf/14_SODRE2.pdf). Como te disse, há periodicamente escritores ingleses a escreverem best-sellers sobre as aventuras dos portugueses [tens aqui outro escrito 20 anos antes](https://www.wook.pt/livro/the-first-global-village-martin-page/78492). Quanto à *"reputação dos académicos"* não acredito nisso, não faltam academicos dispostos a vender a alma ao diabo se alguém lhes pagar os royalties, acho esse excerto de que fizeste copy-paste mal fundamentado e francamente desagradável.

Comment: @bad_coder Sim, eu passei anos que chegue no mundo académico para chegar à mesma conclusão.

Comment: Geralmente, quando lês esses cronistas ingleses ficas com a impressão que Vasco da Gama e o Infante Dom Henrique eram ingleses... Alias, segundo muitos autores ingleses aquilo nos navios portugueses eram tudo descobridores ingleses não havia lá nenhum português.

Comment: @bad_coder Ou seja, ingleses a serem ingleses...